# Creating replica of data using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have dictiony which contains 36 data items. I want to replicate each record 100 times. So total records would be 3600.

```
def createDataReplication(text_list):
    data_item = {}
    print(len(text_list))
    for k,v in text_list.iteritems():
        for i in range(0,100):
            data_item[k+str(i)] = v
    print(len(data_item))
```

output

```
36
3510
```

Why it's 3510 and not 3600? Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: let `a = [{'amount': 400.0, 'currency': 'USD', 'tid': 7072},{'amount': 100.0, 'currency': 'RS', 'tid': 7070}]` then do `a*10` and check the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concatenation `k+str(i)` is repeated for some combinations of `k` and `i`. Dictionary keys must be unique. This causes existing keys to be overwritten.

I suggest you use `tuple` keys instead which, in addition, aligns data structure with your logic:

```
for k, v in text_list.iteritems():
    for i in range(100):
        data_item[(k, i)] = v
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider that a key like `'110'` could be created in two ways:

`k+str(i) = '1' + str(10)` or 
`k+str(i) = '11' + str(0)`.

You need to replace `k+str(i)` with something that is guaranteed to create unique key values. One way to do that is make the key a tuple: `(k, i)`:

```
data_item[k,i] = v
```